# How can i get the last word of a string linux

Tags: linux

For example:
im in this directory, for example, "home/linux/downloads/dir1" and I want to show the files in another directory.

I use: `find /home/linux/files/`

This command shows the files of the previous path like this:

```
/home/linux/files/file1.txt
/home/linux/files/file2.txt
```

using `cut -d "/" -f4` i get `file1.txt` but if you change the path, this command no longer serves me.

There is a command that allows me to always get the last word of a string separated by `/`?

Comment: your tag shows it's python but why your temporary solution is in shell? if you want it in shell `basename $path`.

Comment: Yes, because I'm working with python with shell commands.

Sorry if the title is a bit confusing. I am new here.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
path = '/home/linux/files/dir1'
lastdir = path.split('/')[-1]
```

yields 'dir1'

Comment: no. it's not portable. `os.path.basename` is a function for this.

Comment: Is the question about python or linux shell ??

Comment: You can get the operating system's path delimiter.

Answer (score 4):

[`basename`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/basename) is what you want, because you're asking about *paths*.  In Python it's [`os.path.basename()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find`'s `-exec` for this:

```
find <directory> -exec basename {} \;
```

This will work in any directory. `-exec` tells `find` to execute the command for every file found. Here the command is `basename`, which returns only the file name without directory prefixes. Hope it helps.